# Updating URL address after AJAX call to a 302

Tags: jquery, ajax

After I do an AJAX request with jQuery, I want to update the URL, with the following code

```
history.pushState(object, title, new_url)
```

So I wrote the following code

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: onSuccess
})

var onSuccess = function() {
    ...
    history.pushState(object, title, new_url)
}
```

The problem is that the URL where I go make the AJAX call returns a 302 code, so I need a way to find out where is the final URL.

Is there a way to find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you see if this works in your case ..

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr),
})

var onSuccess = function(data, xhr, textStatus) {
    ...
    if( xhr.status == 200 ) history.pushState(object, title, new_url)
}
```

EDIT:

I have tested with my live site and I console.log'ed final dest URL successfully with this:

```
(function($){

var xhr;
var _orgAjax = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
  xhr = _orgAjax();
  return xhr;
};


$.ajax({
    url: "https://vizkultura.hr/dizajn",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log( xhr.responseURL );
    },
});

})(jQuery)
```

outputed new url: https://vizkultura.hr/dizajn-07-12/

try it @your end and see if it fits, 
cheers, k

Comment: I guess I have misunderstood your question,, you want to find out the final URL after redirection right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to find out

Comment: This actually works! Could you explain a little what is going on?

Comment: if I understand if correctly,, jQuery does not give us full access to native browser xhr object ,, and this does bypasses it for us so we can compare it with starting url :)

Comment: This is quite badass! Mad props, brother!